# the ajax request returns 500 internal server error using laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

i'm having a problem , i'm sending data using post request mentioned below :

```
$.post('/blog/ajax/' , {postid : "x"} , function(data){ 
alert(data);
});
```

and in the routes .php file :

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::post('/ajax','AjaxController@test');
    });`

and in the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
function test()
{
$semester = Input::get('postid');
return $semester;
}
}
?>
```

i've already added the line of

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

i can see that post_id is sent with the value that i've already set.

Comment: Start with reading error logs.

Comment: First format code in your question. And include exact error. 500 says nothing

Comment: @u_mulder where i can find the error logs.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek sir that is the status code

Comment: @Desha Yes, but status code says nothing. You can have thousands reasons why you are getting 500 error. You should include exact error you are getting on screen or you are getting from your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your controller:

```
use Input;
```